# Java Input Empty show alert

Tags: java, string, joptionpane

I'm doing a small project in Java whilst I'm learning the language.

Basically what I'd like is for a user to input a string via `JOptionPane.showInputDialog();`, if that string is empty, I want it to make them re-enter a valid string and then the program will continue.

What I did consider doing is using `goto` but I read up on it and it said it's not good practice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: `goto` is definitely not good practice in Java, where its only effect is rendering your program uncompilable.

Comment: Other than the "goto", what have you tried?

Comment: Nothing, I'm completely stumped on what I can do.

Comment: Java doesn't *have* `goto`. It's a reserved keyword but it was never implemented.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it in an infinite loop asking for input (using `OptionPane.showInputDialog()`).
Here you have some pseudo code:

```
message = ""
while message.equals(""):
    message = ask_for_input() // (.trim() if needed)
end
```

Comment: +1 For added strictness, if needed, use `message = ask_for_input().trim() ` (to prevent whitespace-only Strings as well as "truly empty" ones).

Comment: Shall do in a sec, it says I have to wait for 2 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in a loop. So you take a while-loop where the condition is that the input is empty. Then the message will pop up until the user entered something.

Answer (score 2):

Despite `goto` is a reserved keyword in Java, it's actually (implicitly) meant for **not** being used.

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)` returns a `String`.

I suggest using an infinite `while` loop and comparing it to empty, through `String.isEmpty()`.

For instance:

```
String input = null;
while (true) {
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your input (not empty):");
    if (!input.trim().isEmpty()) {
        // TODO something with the input variable
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what `do ... while` loops are for.  You could also use the Apache commons `StringUtils` class.

```
String input;
do {
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your string");
} while (StringUtils.isBlank(input));
```